# Array Wrapper class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, wrapper

So, I'm new to C++ (brand new), and as an assignment I have to write a class that acts as an array wrapper. Since I'm so new, I'm unsure whether my overloaded operators and such work, so if anyone could be so kind as to tell me how my code looks:

This would be the header:

```
class MyArray
{

private:
    string* sList;
    unsigned int size;

public:
    MyArray(const unsigned int size = 1);
    MyArray(const MyArray &toCopy);
    MyArray& operator=(const MyArray& toAssign);
    ~MyArray();
    //MyArray& operator+
    string& operator[](const int index);
    const int size();
};
```

And this would be the underlying code:

```
MyArray::MyArray(const unsigned int initSize)
    : size(initSize)
{
    sList = new string[initSize];
    return;
}

MyArray::MyArray(const MyArray &toCopy)
    : size(toCopy.size)
{
    if(toCopy.sList)
    {
        sList = new string[size];
        for(int a=0; a<size; a++){
            strcpy(sList[a], toCopy.sList[a]);
        }

    }
    else sList = NULL;
    return;

}

MyArray& operator=(const MyArray& toAssign)
{
    if(this != &toAssign)
    {
        if(sList)
        {
            delete [] sList;
        }

        size = toAssign.size;

        if (toAssign.sList)
        {
            sList = new string[size];

            for(int a=0; a<size; a++){
                strcpy(sList[a], toCopy.sList[a]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sList = NULL
        }
    }
}

MyArray::~MyArray()
{
    delete [] sList;
    return;
}

string& MyArray::operator[](const int index)
{
    return sList[index];
}


const int MyArray::size()
{
    return this.size;
}
```

The operator+ function still needs to be written, but I want to make sure what I have makes sense before I proceed.

Comment: You should probably test it and run it a few times before asking for help so you know what specifically we can help you with.

Comment: Write your requirements as unit tests and then you'll know if your operators work or not.

Comment: Step it with a debugger - you will see exactly how it works then.

Comment: This isn't a question.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want your code (i.e. the class you are authoring) to be used by other programmers (including you)?

**Write an example program to demonstrate the use of your class.**

An example program serves as a rudimentary test set. You can start as the following.

```
int main() {
    MyArray arr1( 5 );
    MyArray arr2( arr1 );
}
```

Have you thought about how user code will put (string?) elements into the `MyArray` class?

There are couple of other issues with the current version of the code. That is okay to begin with, but it is important for you to learn to test your own code; you need to learn the skill where you have some basic confidence in your own code (not necessarily perfect code) because you cannot always ask somebody else to test your code.

Suggestion: Since you mentioned that you are new, I would suggest you to build a array wrapper class for `int`'s first. This is because, managing `string`s has some extra challenges than managing `int`s :-). Once you do that, you can easily do it for `string`s.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a naming conflict between `size` and `size()`
- Copy C++ strings using `=`, not `strcpy` (which is for `char*`)
- Missing `MyArray::` in definition of `operator=`
- `toCopy` should be `toAssign` in `operator=`
- Missing semicolon after `sList = NULL`
- Missing `return *this;` at the end of `operator=`
- In defintion of `size()`, `this.size` should be `size`, `this->size` or `(*this).size`

All of these mistakes will be discovered by a compiler (you may need to enable warnings for the missing return to be reported; on `g++` use the `-Wall` flag). It is just a matter of understanding the compiler's error messages and knowing how to fix the problems.